# Measuring current with a microcontroller

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, battery-charging, current-measurement, shunt

I'm doing a project that involves sensing current. I'm charging a battery and I need to control how much current and voltage I'm giving out.

I thought that it would be okay to use an SCR like a 40tps controlled by an MOC3021 optocoupler.

The part I have doubts about: I know because of common-mode voltage that current with a shunt and a simple operational amplifier has to be measured at the low side of the battery ( - ).

I saw a lot of circuits that are especially made for sensing the current with a external shunt, but do I need this if I'm okay with an error of about 0.5%? I want to measure around 30 A max and 1 A min. I saw some shunts of 0.5 mΩ and 9 W; that will be fine.

I have a lot of trouble to find and understand the dedicated amplifiers for that. Could you suggest a circuit with an LM358 for instance that will be good for my requirements or do I need a dedicated one?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 1mΩ because the math is easy.
Watts = I^2/R,  30 * 30/0.001 = 900/0.001 = 0.9 watts.
Voltage = I*R, = 30 * 0.001, = 0.03 volts.  max
Voltage = I*R, = 1 * 0.001, = 0.001 volts.  min
What is the voltage range your computer can read?
30mV and 1mV are very small numbers.
Your amplifier has in input offset of 2mV typ, 5mV max.  and at bad as 9mV at extreme temperatures. I think the offset of the amplifier is too much to look at a 1mV signal.
I have used ACS725 current sensor, they make a 0 to 30A and a -30 to +30 version. Look it over.

Comment: Yes, seems not viable... I saw something about ACS725 but its a little bit to expensive for this project... I also saw another one, ACS711KEXLT-30AU-T . This one its more cheap and has a sensitivity of 90mV/A. Im reading this analog output with an ADC of a PIC16f15223, so i think that if i had 1Amp its enought, because it will be 9mV, and the ADC has a resolution of 1024, so it will be: 5v/1024=4.8mV Aprox. Then if its 30A, the value will be: 90mV * 30A = 2.7V max of output. Im correct?

Comment: @samuelmattio Yes, this is correct. There is a trap: Feed the sensor supply via an MCU port bit. Then you can reset the chip after an overcurrent event.